# Trying to use Shuffle.js but getting Uncaught TypeError: Shuffle is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shuffle

This ought to be a simple enough question for those in the know- why am I getting this error in my console? I have tried following along with the code that appears under "usage" on the [Shuffle homepage](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) but I think the page is neglecting to include all of the steps for getting started with the library.

Here is my code on my index file located within the shufflejs folder created when the library was installed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Shuffle Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">       
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="grid" class="row my-shuffle-container">
<figure class="col-4@sm picture-item" data-groups='["photography"]' data-date-created="2010-09-14" data-title="Baseball">
<div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
  <div class="aspect__inner">
    <img src="/img/baseball.png" alt="" height="145" width="230">
  </div>
</div>
<figcaption>Baseball</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="col-4@sm picture-item" data-groups='["wallpaper","3d"]' data-date-created="2011-08-14" data-title="Tennis">
<div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
  <div class="aspect__inner">
    <img src="/img/tennis-ball.png" alt="" height="145" width="230">
  </div>
</div>
<figcaption>Tennis</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="col-4@sm picture-item" data-groups='["wallpaper","3d"]' data-date-created="2009-05-27" data-title="iMac">
<div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
  <div class="aspect__inner">
    <img src="/img/imac.png" alt="" height="145" width="230">
  </div>
</div>
<figcaption>iMac</figcaption>
</figure>
<div class="col-1@sm my-sizer-element"></div>
</div>

<script>
var Shuffle = window.shuffle;
var element = document.getElementById('grid');
var sizer = element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element');

var shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
itemSelector: '.picture-item',
sizer: sizer // could also be a selector: '.my-sizer-element'
});
// Overrideable options
Shuffle.options = {
group: Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS, // Initial filter group.
speed: 250, // Transition/animation speed (milliseconds).
easing: 'ease', // CSS easing function to use.
itemSelector: '*', // e.g. '.picture-item'.
sizer: null, // Element or selector string. Use an element to determine     the size of columns and gutters.
gutterWidth: 0, // A static number or function that tells the plugin how wide the gutters between columns are (in pixels).
columnWidth: 0, // A static number or function that returns a number which tells the plugin how wide the columns are (in pixels).
delimeter: null, // If your group is not json, and is comma delimeted, you could set delimeter to ','.
buffer: 0, // Useful for percentage based heights when they might not always be exactly the same (in pixels).
columnThreshold: 0.01, // Reading the width of elements isn't precise enough and can cause columns to jump between values.
initialSort: null, // Shuffle can be initialized with a sort object. It is the same object given to the sort method.
throttle: throttle, // By default, shuffle will throttle resize events. This can be changed or removed.
throttleTime: 300, // How often shuffle can be called on resize (in milliseconds).
staggerAmount: 15, // Transition delay offset for each item in milliseconds.
staggerAmountMax: 250, // Maximum stagger delay in milliseconds.
useTransforms: true, // Whether to use transforms or absolute positioning.
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't including the ShuffleJS file in your code.

Comment: @yuriy636 Ah yes, that removed that error- but now I seem to be in a loop of separate uncaught reference errors. Serious question- why wouldn't Shuffle's documentation have an actual getting started guide? Lots of js libraries I've seen are very explicit in how they are set up while Shuffle is the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not completed. To create the Shuffle home page effect Your script should look like this.

```
'use strict';

var Shuffle = window.shuffle;

var Demo = function (element) {
  this.element = element;

  // Log out events.
  this.addShuffleEventListeners();

  this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
    itemSelector: '.picture-item',
    sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
  });

  this._activeFilters = [];

  this.addFilterButtons();
  this.addSorting();
  this.addSearchFilter();

  this.mode = 'exclusive';
};

Demo.prototype.toArray = function (arrayLike) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);
};

Demo.prototype.toggleMode = function () {
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    this.mode = 'exclusive';
  } else {
    this.mode = 'additive';
  }
};

/**
 * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
 * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example). The extra event
 * data is in the `detail` property.
 */
Demo.prototype.addShuffleEventListeners = function () {
  var handler = function (event) {
    console.log('type: %s', event.type, 'detail:', event.detail);
  };

  this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, handler, false);
  this.element.addEventListener(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, handler, false);
};

Demo.prototype.addFilterButtons = function () {
  var options = document.querySelector('.filter-options');

  if (!options) {
    return;
  }

  var filterButtons = this.toArray(
    options.children
  );

  filterButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', this._handleFilterClick.bind(this), false);
  }, this);
};

Demo.prototype._handleFilterClick = function (evt) {
  var btn = evt.currentTarget;
  var isActive = btn.classList.contains('active');
  var btnGroup = btn.getAttribute('data-group');

  // You don't need _both_ of these modes. This is only for the demo.

  // For this custom 'additive' mode in the demo, clicking on filter buttons
  // doesn't remove any other filters.
  if (this.mode === 'additive') {
    // If this button is already active, remove it from the list of filters.
    if (isActive) {
      this._activeFilters.splice(this._activeFilters.indexOf(btnGroup));
    } else {
      this._activeFilters.push(btnGroup);
    }

    btn.classList.toggle('active');

    // Filter elements
    this.shuffle.filter(this._activeFilters);

  // 'exclusive' mode lets only one filter button be active at a time.
  } else {
    this._removeActiveClassFromChildren(btn.parentNode);

    var filterGroup;
    if (isActive) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
      filterGroup = Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS;
    } else {
      btn.classList.add('active');
      filterGroup = btnGroup;
    }

    this.shuffle.filter(filterGroup);
  }
};

Demo.prototype._removeActiveClassFromChildren = function (parent) {
  var children = parent.children;
  for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    children[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};

Demo.prototype.addSorting = function () {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.sort-options');

  if (!menu) {
    return;
  }

  menu.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
};

Demo.prototype._handleSortChange = function (evt) {
  var value = evt.target.value;
  var options = {};

  function sortByDate(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-created');
  }

  function sortByTitle(element) {
    return element.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase();
  }

  if (value === 'date-created') {
    options = {
      reverse: true,
      by: sortByDate,
    };
  } else if (value === 'title') {
    options = {
      by: sortByTitle,
    };
  }

  this.shuffle.sort(options);
};

// Advanced filtering
Demo.prototype.addSearchFilter = function () {
  var searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-shuffle-search');

  if (!searchInput) {
    return;
  }

  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', this._handleSearchKeyup.bind(this));
};

/**
 * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
 * @param {Event} evt Event object.
 */
Demo.prototype._handleSearchKeyup = function (evt) {
  var searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();

  this.shuffle.filter(function (element, shuffle) {

    // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
    if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
      // Get the item's groups.
      var groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
      var isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;

      // Only search elements in the current group
      if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    var titleElement = element.querySelector('.picture-item__title');
    var titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();

    return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
});
```

Replace your script code with this and It should work.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks very much Sasith.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding `shuffle.min.js` to my files instead of using a CDN. It worked using just:

```
var Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
var el = document.querySelector('#shuffle');
var shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(el,{
    itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with this to see if the div ID exists on that page:

```
if ($('#my-shuffle-container').length > 0) {

}
```